Is there evidence that inversion therapy helps prevent certain types of headaches?
I had regular headache attacks (also with migraine symptoms) since my youth. Sometimes loosely correlated with my menstrual cycle, but not strictly synced. Around one year ago, I discovered that hanging upside down (head lower than the body core) immediately gave me symptoms very similar to my normal headache. So I decided it's worth trying to learn to tolerate this body position, to check if this reduces my headache frequency/severity. So I started to get upside down (shallower angles and short duration at the beginning) daily (on days without headache) and slowly increased the duration and the angle. Today I can tolerate around 1 minute of complete inversion. And now I had no headache for a few months already, which never happened before!
Of course, this is no clinical evidence, and one needs a proper study with a randomized control group, etc. to prove any efficacy. So I wonder if any of you know about studies that tested it.

My searches on the web did not yield what I was looking for. The most relevant hits are these:

Research has shown that during a migraine attack, the blood in the brain is depleted in oxygen. Inversion therapy floods the brain with more blood flow and thus more oxygen. I would recommend inversion therapy more as a preventative treatment for migraines rather than a means of treatment during a migraine attack.

source: https://www.livestrong.com/article/116107-inversion-table-benefits/

While we have had many customers tell us that inverting has decreased the frequency of their occasional headaches or migraines, we are unaware of any studies that have been conducted to determine if there is any correlation.

source: https://teeter.com/blog/faq-will-inversion-help-headaches-migraines

If there is no clinical experimental data yet, perhaps it's worth conducting such a study! :)

I’m voting to close this question because soliciting the personal experiences of others is off-topic here.

@BryanKrause Ah, you're right, good point. I edited my question, i.e., I removed the part asking about other people's experiences.

Okay, that's a good start, but this site also requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research. So I agree that your anecdotal experience isn't evidence, but is there evidence out there? Have you looked? Try googling inversion+therapy+migraine and if that doesn't pan out, try it on google scholar. The point is, you don't have to answer your own question, but you do have to show that you tried.

@CareyGregory Ah, got it, thanks! I did the googling beforehand but did not find anything helpful. I did not mention it, but I should have. I've edited my question accordingly.

I couldn't find any completed studies on inversion therapy for headaches, although I found one article describing a proposal for a very small (N=20) study of inversion for headache prophylaxis, no evidence of completion or results. It appears that your own research was pretty much what's out there. Sorry. The use of inversion has been discouraged historically b/c of potential risks (elevated BP, IOP, stroke risk) and it's suggested that you should have a doctor's approval before undertaking it. ...

...However, a non-pharmacologic approach would be most welcome by patients and physicians, I should think (I certainly appreciate them.) But then the question arises re. funding... if no-one stands to profit from a non-pharmacological approach, how will good studies be financed? (A cynical view, indeed; apologies.) The medical literature of foreign countries that rely more on non-pharmacological approaches might be more informative. Good question without a good answer. I hope someone else can address this more satisfactorily.

@anongoodnurse Thanks a lot! Maybe companies selling inversion tables could profit from it. :D But yeah, I get your point. It would be cool if more studies were done just for the sake of helping humanity.

Agreed1 I should add that the risks of inversion in healthy people without hypertension, diabetes or glaucoma may be insignificant; heavy weight lifting, astronauts, gymnasts, etc. endure physical challenges that are far more demanding than simple inversion done correctly. I remember when inversion was used for treatment of back pain (unhelpful); people weren't stroking out left and right. In your place, I might let migraine researchers know of your experience. Can't hurt! Good luck. :)

@anongoodnurse Thanks! I've just searched for headache research facilities on the web and sent emails with my study suggestions to a few of them. It would be amazing if someone would conduct such a clinical trial and if it turns out that this type of therapy can contribute to the reduction of headache suffering in the world. :)

Wonderful! I hope it gets the attention it deserves. Wouldn't that be something?
